# Comfortable way of working with shared libs

Tags: node.js, npm, microservices

I have back-end project which is based on microservices architecture. Also I have one shared lib which is hosted in verdaccio service. Everything works well, but the routine of editing shared lib is boring. Every time I need to build lib, push to git, wait until it is builded there, then install it in my microservices and only then can go. During testing and debugging locally I just copy/paste dist folder, which, I feel, is not good idea and still, before push it I have to update npm lock file, so it is not a solution.
Maybe there is some tool which can automate this process?

UPD `npm link` is a solution

Comment: I think this is what "npm link" is for. Instead of using a published package you can point the package reference to a directory on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

In microservices architecture is usually a bad practice to have common libraries used by all the microservices because this way you are coupling these services and copling its lifecycles because every time a new version of the library is released all the services need to be updated and new versions of them are needed.

The general solution of this problem is that every service should have its own dependencies so the team that works on it doesn't need or depends on other teams or lifecycles of other artifacts.

However, it could be certain functionality that is needed to be the same for all services and duplicate it among all microservices, could be worse. In this cases, in my opinion, it is not bad to share a library, the same as other libraries that alredy they share like lombok, jackson, etc. The requirement in these situations will be that the library is stable (it is not expected to have many bugs or changes) and that it could maintain various versions without problem (if one microservice is in version x and it doesnt need any change of the new version of the library, it should not need to update until an update is required by its own business requirements, so its lifecycle is not altered)